# Invalid indentation, you can use tabs or spaces but not both jade

Tags: node.js, pug

i have following jade code which works fine

```
div.container
  h3.entry-title(style='margin-top:25px;') #{result.post_title}
  div      
    p.text-left.pst <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> #{result.post_date}  
  div.panel
     !{result.post_content}
    -if(typeof userType !== 'undefined' && userType=='admin')
        a.btn.red.marginTop(href='/ebs' ) Cancel               

 div.page-footer
    div.page-footer-inner
        Copyright Copyright All rights reserved.
```

but when i try to insert if statement like below it gives me the indentation error

```
  div.container
  h3.entry-title(style='margin-top:25px;') #{result.post_title}
  div   
   -if(result.post_date!='-1')  
    p.text-left.pst <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> #{result.post_date}  
  div.panel
     !{result.post_content}
    -if(typeof userType !== 'undefined' && userType=='admin')
        a.btn.red.marginTop(href='/ebs' ) Cancel               

 div.page-footer
    div.page-footer-inner
        Copyright Copyright  All rights reserved.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using Sublime text editor, you can go to View > Identation > Convert Identation to spaces.

Answer (score 3):

Find an option in your editor to highlight/show tabs or spaces.  Or just delete all indentation and re-add it using only tabs or only spaces carefully.

Answer (score 1):

It may be due to while providing spaces in your code lines, u provided some space with tab and some space with spacebar. 
Try to use "ONLY" spacebar or "ONLY" Tab button for single line.

i.e. for this code line "      $(document).ready(function(){" either provide space with tab only or space only.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using vscode just install an extension called "Pug beautify" and it will do the work for you

Answer (score 0):

> `Pug(formerly Jade)` template works on identical indention.
>
> You need to choose `space or tab` in your `pug` file. You can't use both.

Choose common indent from your editor and out from this weird error